# Most efficient way to convert Long to string?

Tags: java, long-integer

If I have a Long (not the primitive) whats the best way to convert it to a string. By best, I mean fastest.

Currently, I'm doing this.

```java
Long testLong = 123456L;
return new StringBuilder()
               .append(PREFIX)
               .append("_")
               .append(testLong)
               .toString();
```

is `String.valueOf(testLong)` or `testLong.toString()` better?

Comment: Have you tried running any benchmarks to see which fits your need the best?

Comment: Don't they both use `static String Long.toString(long)`?

Comment: `String.valueOf(long l)` and the non-static `toString()` method of `Long` both just call the static `Long.toString(long l)` method. So it should be literally no difference at all.

Comment: What's up with the `PREFIX` and underscore in your stringbuilder? Are you asking how to append a long to a string or how to convert a long (only) to a string?

Comment: What you're already doing is best. You will not notice any performance difference between `append(testLong)`, `append(String.valueOf(testLong))`, and `append(testLong.toString())`, so you should write the code that's most **logical**, which is `append(testLong)`. The actual performance difference between those 3 calls is minuscule compared to the actual conversion of a `long` to a `String`. Don't micro-optimize your code like this, write code that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`.append(testLong)` calls `.append(String.valueOf(testLong))`.

`.append(String.valueOf(testLong))` calls `.append((testLong == null) ? "null" : testLong.toString())`

`.append(testLong.toString())` calls `.append(Long.toString(testLong.value))` (where `value` is the boxed `long`), which creates a `new String`

`.append(testLong.longValue())` does not create a new `String`, instead, it writes directly to the `StringBuilder` byte array.

Therefore the latter is the fastest, if you know that the `Long` will never be `null`:

```
Long testLong = 123456L;
return new StringBuilder()
               .append(PREFIX)
               .append("_")
               .append(testLong.longValue())
               .toString();
```